# Could not load file or assembly System.ComponentModel.Annotations. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, azure, assembly-binding-redirect

I am using assembly binding, but I still get this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Here is my code:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Here are more details on the error:

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C://Source/Workspaces/CQB/Development/Dev-branch/Azure/CloudService1/csx/Debug/roles/CQB.TaskRole2/approot
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Source\Workspaces\CQB\Development\Dev-branch\Azure\CloudService1\csx\Debug\roles\CQB.TaskRole2\approot

## Calling assembly : Square.Connect, Version=2.25.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Source\Workspaces\CQB\Development\Dev-branch\Azure\CloudService1\csx\Debug\roles\CQB.TaskRole2\approot\CQB.TaskRole2.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.2.0.0 redirected to 4.2.1.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C://Source/Workspaces/CQB/Development/Dev-branch/Azure/CloudService1/csx/Debug/roles/CQB.TaskRole2/approot/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C://Source/Workspaces/CQB/Development/Dev-branch/Azure/CloudService1/csx/Debug/roles/CQB.TaskRole2/approot/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C://Source/Workspaces/CQB/Development/Dev-branch/Azure/CloudService1/csx/Debug/roles/CQB.TaskRole2/approot/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C://Source/Workspaces/CQB/Development/Dev-branch/Azure/CloudService1/csx/Debug/roles/CQB.TaskRole2/approot/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.EXE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the version showing for `Version 4.5.0` in the library reference properties is `4.2.1.0`. When I changed the `version to 4.4.1` via NuGet, the version in the properties changed to `4.2.0.0`.

So change the version of `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` to `4.4.1` via nuget will resolve the issue for me.